# is Spread operator available in strict mode in Nodejs ?

Tags: node.js

is Spread operator available in strict mode in Nodejs ? , example :

```
"use strict"

class LongAggregationQuery {
    constructor(...aggregationQueries){
        this.aggregationQueries=aggregationQueries;
   }
}
```

Comment: Not directly yet, but with the `--harmony` flag

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is available in strict mode and without --harmony Flag. See  ["Which features ship with Node.js by default (no runtime flag required)?"](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/#which-features-ship-with-node-js-by-default-no-runtime-flag-required)

**UPDATE**

see http://node.green/ for implementation state of ES6 features (like e.g. spread operator).

Comment: Ive tried using spread operator using Node 6.1.0 (with use strict) and get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

Comment: there is a link which is a bit hidden in the linked text. I updated my answer and added the direct link